# byte-sized bit pattern in C and its relevance?

Tags: c

I a reading Kerninghan and Ritchie's C programming language book and on page 37 it mentions byte sized bit patterns like :

`'\013'` for vertical tab .

`'\007'` for bell character .

My doubts :

1. What is byte sized in it and and what's a bit pattern ?
2. What relevance does this hold and where can I apply it ?
3. Is it in any sense related to escape sequences ?

I can't seem to find any information what so ever about these byte sized bit patterns on the web . please help . thanks .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. A byte is 8 bits. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte)
2. A bit pattern is the bits that make up the data. E.g. The octal value (i.e. `'\007`) is converted to the bit pattern (most significant bit first) would be 0000 0111. `'\013'` would be the bit pattern 0000 1011
3. You typically use these escape sequences for non-printable characters.
4. `'\007'` is an escape sequence. So is `'\\'`.

Comment: The c standard uses "byte" to mean the storage size of a `char`. That's an octet on essentially every machine you can find these days, but isn't actually guaranteed to be 8 bits. Not that there is anything wrong with this answer, just for the pedantry of it.

Comment: @dmckee - I was just keeping the answer simple. I know that a byte can be more or less that 8 bits - but cannot think of any machine that uses anything other than 8 bits. Can you?

Comment: Very old Burroughs used 9.  I think old Cray may have used 32 or 64.  Not aware of anything recent.

Comment: A couple of years ago I was looking at the spec for a microcontroler we were considering for a custom board. Don't recall which one just now, but it had 12 bit words...

Comment: @DrC - I think that part of the standard is just there for historical reasons. I vaguely remember a mainframe (cannot recall the make) that used 7 bits. I think it is safe to say that you can assume that it is 8 bits. Embedded systems is another matter. All sorts of weird things happen there.

Comment: Nope...I think I misremembered. The AVR I was looking at has 12 ADCs which is not at all the same thing.

Comment: how can I compare a bit pattern '00001011' using '\007' in a program .Can you please show it with some code ?

Answer (score 5):

When C was first developed and used the original target was the [PDP-11 minicomputer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11).  The PDP-11 had a 16 bit processor.  At the time most input was done with some version of a [teletype terminal or teleprinter terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) (a keyboard with printed paper rather than a Cathode Ray Tube).  Later [Cathode Ray Tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube) types of terminals were put into place such as the [DEC-VT100 terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) replacing the paper types of terminals.

These terminals were connected to the host computer using cables to communicate between terminal and host computer. For short cable runs the [RS-232 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) was used, often using only three of the 25 pins (transmit, receive, and ground) with software handshake between terminal and host computer. The [RS-422 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) was used for longer cable runs. Data transmission rates for direct connections were typically 9600 [baud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud) or 14,400 baud.

In the case of remote terminals using the [Public Switched Telephone Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_switched_telephone_network) to reach the host computer, a [modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) was used at each end of the connection to convert and unconvert digital signals into acoustic signals for transmission over the telephone line. Characters typed on the terminal key board were transmitted to the host computer over the cable. Most modems used some variation of the defacto [Hayes command set standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set).

The PDP-11 used the [ASCII character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) which used a seven bit code to represent each character with the eighth bit being used to implement a simple [parity error checking protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).  Later the ASCII character set was extended by using the parity bit as part of the character in order to add characters from European languages to develop the Extended ASCII and the ANSI character sets as well as the [ANSI escape code sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for setting text colors on CRT type displays.

The original ASCII code had a section of codes that were used for terminal control such as to ring the bell, vertical and horizontal tabs, new lines or end of line, etc.  There were also codes that were used to create simple protocols such as Start and Stop codes.  One such default standard to use the Escape character to indicate the beginning of a control sequence such as the beginning of a text color or to move the cursor to a particular row and column on the display.

With modern Graphical User Interfaces, most of this is fairly old and unused though there are still [terminal emulators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) that which will translate the ANSI escape codes into various display behaviors within a graphical window.

So when Kerninghan and Ritchie were developing C and the Unix operating system on a PDP-11 they were working within an environment of the DEC PDP-11 instruction set, the ASCII character set, and the PDP-11 peripherals such as teleprinters.

So they naturally settled on text strings being composed of 8 bit characters with ways to embed special control characters into the strings in order to ring the bell of the teleprinter and to control the typing head as lines of text are printed.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a mechanism for entering character (byte) values in base 8 (octal).  Typically used to add control and similar characters in a string or char constant.

Comment: "Typically used to add control and similar characters in a string or char constant." So basically it can be taken as a form of an escape character ?

Comment: I hesitated to answer that part to avoid some confusion.   The \ is an escape mechanism in that it interrupts the normal processing of characters in a char or string constant.   Also, if you want to enter THE escape character, you can use \033 (if I've done the math correctly).  The pattern \xxx is a mechanism for entering a character constant that is prefixed by an escape - it isn't really an escape in itself.